# how can I determine that an element height is fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to know whether an HTML element will expand as the content is added to it. The height of the element can be preset in a number of ways - with the inline style height or max-height, by setting relative height when the parent element has its height set, via a css class, etc.

All I need to know whether the height of the element will increase as I add children. I hoped to use the JQuery css method, but it computes the actual value and does not tell me whether it will change as new children are added.

Comment: http://gregpettit.ca/2012/jquery-check-if-element-has-auto-widthheight/

Comment: @epascarello try to change it and see if it does - this might work... feels kludgy though. I was thinking about traversing the css/element tree, but this is more than I would like to take on at the moment

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to set a height of the element. Here is a test function you can use in order to determine if specified element has fixed height:

**HTML**

```
<span id="notAffected"></span>
<div id="hasCSSHeight"/>
<div id="hasInlineHeight" style="height:50px"/>
<div id="hasAttribureHeight" height="10px" />
<div id="hasNoHeight"/>
```

**CSS**

```
#notAffected,
#hasCSSHeight {
  height: 100px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function hasHeight(el) {
  var i,
      l,
      rules = window.getMatchedCSSRules(el),
      display = window.getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('display');

  // Inline displayed elements are not affected by height definition
  if(display === 'inline') {
    return false;
  }

  // CSS
  if(rules) {
    for(i=0,l=rules.length;i<l;i++) {
      if(rules[i].style.getPropertyValue('height')) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  // Inline style
  if(el.style.height) {
    return true;
  }

  // Attribute
  if(el.getAttribute('height')) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Example see here http://jsbin.com/usojec/3/edit

Comment: Hmm... I do not think this is complete. What about height relative height? AFAIK for relative height the answer to my question will depend on the parent element - right? Am I missing anything else?

Comment: @mfeingold Can you explain what you mean by relative height? If it's specifying height in `%`, than the function in the answer will work as well.

Comment: here is a quote from MDN: Percentages The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to auto. A percentage height on the root element is relative to the initial containing block.